# Making a list from a pandas column containing multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's use this as an example data set:

```
    Year    Breeds
0   2009    Collie
1   2010    Shepherd
2   2011    Collie, Shepherd
3   2012    Shepherd, Retriever
4   2013    Shepherd
5   2014    Shepherd, Bulldog
6   2015    Collie, Retriever
7   2016    Retriever, Bulldog
```

I want to create a list `dogs` in which `dogs` contains the unique dog breeds `Collie, Shepherd, Retriever, Bulldog`.  I know it is as simple as calling `.unique()` on the appropriate column, but I am running into the issue of having more than one value in the `Breeds` column. Any ideas to circumvent that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

If need extract all possible values use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['new'] = df['Breeds'].str.split(', ')
```

For unique values  convert to `set`s:

```
df['new'] = df['Breeds'].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [list(set(x.split(', '))) for x in df['Breeds']]
```

---

Use [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for extract by `list` and `regex` - `|` for `OR` if want extract only some values:

```
L = ["Collie", "Shepherd", "Retriever", "Bulldog"]

df['new'] = df['Breeds'].str.findall('|'.join(L))
```

If possible duplicates:

```
df['new'] = df['Breeds'].str.findall('|'.join(L)).apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

---

```
print (df)
   Year               Breeds                    new
0  2009               Collie               [Collie]
1  2010             Shepherd             [Shepherd]
2  2011     Collie, Shepherd     [Collie, Shepherd]
3  2012  Shepherd, Retriever  [Shepherd, Retriever]
4  2013             Shepherd             [Shepherd]
5  2014    Shepherd, Bulldog    [Shepherd, Bulldog]
6  2015    Collie, Retriever    [Collie, Retriever]
7  2016   Retriever, Bulldog   [Retriever, Bulldog]
```